# harvmac tex implemented in the Texshop of Mac?

Tags: texshop

This is just a specific question for using harvmac.tex type of file.

This type of file has something beginning with

```
\input harvmac
\input amssym
\input epsf
```

Does this harvmac tex file can be implemented in the Texshop of Mac?

I use LaTex in Texshop for years, but I haven not succeeded in the case of harvmac tex running in the Texshop of Mac.

Please help if you can, thank you all for even the little attentions.

Comment: The harvmac.tex is a package on the so called
`plain tex`. Thus it may be difficult for you to write
a document by using it for the first time.
If you have a source `test.tex` written by someone,
try on the `terminal`:
`etex test.tex`, `dvips -o test.ps test.dvi`,
`ps2pdf test.ps test.pdf`.

Comment: @ Akira Kakuto, thanks if you can say more or write an answer for it -- it will be helpful.